# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting python Flask

Tags: python, mysql, api, flask, sql-insert

I am working on a user register and login API. DB is MySQL. getAllUser is getting Properly. But when i am trying for post method for Inserting a row it's keep throwing this Error.

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

MY CODE: DB structure:

```
 id(autoincrement), usr_name(varchar 30), password(varchar 20)
```

CODE for inserting :

As I am getting all user list perfectly the connections are correct.

```
mysql = MySQL()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'xxx'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'xxx'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'xxx'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'

mysql.init_app(app)


class UserRegister(Resource):
    TABLE_NAME = 'user'

    parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
    parser.add_argument('usr_name',
        required=True,
        help="This field cannot be left blank!"
    )
    parser.add_argument('password',
        required=True,
        help="This field cannot be left blank!"
    )


    def post(self):
        data = UserRegister.parser.parse_args()
        print(data)
        cursor = mysql.connect().cursor()

        query = "INSERT INTO {table} VALUES (NULL, ?, ?)".format(table=self.TABLE_NAME)
        cursor.execute(query, (data['usr_name'], data['password']))

        return {"message": "User created successfully."}, 201
```

Please help.. I really need this .. or any tutorial to follow on.

Comment: Replace query by "INSERT INTO {table} (usr_name, password) VALUES (?, ?)".format(table=self.TABLE_NAME)

Answer (score 0):

ERROR SOLVED

```
def post(self):
            data = UserRegister.parser.parse_args()
            print(data)

        cursor = mysql.connect().cursor()

        username = request.json['usr_name']
        password = request.json['password']

        query = "insert into user values(null,'{0}','{1}')".format(username,password)
        cursor.execute(query)

        return {"message": "User created successfully."}, 201
```